# Local Storage list of favourites

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am using this [codepen](https://codepen.io/CrocoDillon/pen/pIlKB) in my web application and even though it is working on the website, in my case when I refresh the page only the first item of the list is marked as favourite, no matter which ones were marked before the refresh.

```
var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites')) || [];

favorites.forEach(function(favorite) {
  document.getElementById(favorite).className = 'fav';
});

document.querySelector('.list').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var id = e.target.id,
      item = e.target,
      index = favorites.indexOf(id);

  if (!id) return;

  if (index == -1) {
    favorites.push(id);
    item.className = 'fav';

  } else {
    favorites.splice(index, 1);
    item.className = '';
  }

  localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites));
});
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

**[CodePen](https://codepen.io/CrocoDillon/pen/pIlKB)**

Comment: Its working as expected for me. I tested in chrome as well as in firefox.  You can clear the cache or may be `CTRL +F5` will help you.

Comment: Worked for me before as well, but I implemented another feature on a different view which has been using LocalStorage as well. Could it be a conflict?

Comment: Only if you use the same item name.

Comment: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites')) || [];` should be `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites') || '[]');` Your way will get an error from `JSON.parse()` if the item doesn't exist in local storage.

Comment: @mateicoman, you can use different name based on your need. If you want to share the value on different views then you can use same name.